# Retry a different url if cy.visit status returns a 404 status code

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am writing some Cypress tests for my app that should be able to run in both a sandbox environment and staging environment by using Gas Mask spoofing.  The problem is the base url's are slightly different (one uses https and one uses http).  I am trying to get the cy.visit command to use the url starting with http (sandbox) if https (staging) returns a 404 by using a conditional.  Any suggestions would be appreciated! I am trying to do something like this:

```
cy.visit(staging_url,  {
        if (resp.status === 404) {
            cy.visit(sandbox_url)
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `failOnStatusCode: false` to Diogo Rocha's solution:

```
cy.request({staging_url, failOnStatusCode: false}).then((response) => {
 if (response.isOkStatusCode) {
    cy.visit(staging_url);
  } else {
    cy.visit(sandbox_url);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`cy.visit()` yields the `window` object after the page finishes loading, so I don't think you can check the status code only with `cy.visit()`.

I would make something like this:

```
cy.request(staging_url).then((response) => {
  if (response.isOkStatusCode) {
    cy.visit(staging_url);
  } else {
    cy.visit(sandbox_url);
  }
});
```

Comment: No luck with that, I'm still getting this error ```The response we received from your web server was:

  > 404: Not Found

This was considered a failure because the status code was not '2xx' or '3xx'.

If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: 'failOnStatusCode: false'
```  I tried adding in ```failOnStatusCode: false``` as a param on the cy.request but still got the same error.

Comment: You get that error with the cy.request call or in the cy.visit? Cause I got that error in a 404 on cy.visit.

Comment: Getting it on the cy.request, so it seems like it's failing right away on the request and then never hitting the if/else block. It is still working for the staging environment.

Answer (score 0):

Using [cy.intercept](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Waiting-on-a-request) with [cy.wait](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait#Alias) should work as required.

```js
cy.intercept("GET", staging_url).as("staging");

cy.visit(staging_url);

cy.wait("@staging").then((interception) => {
  if (interception.response.statusCode === 404) {
    cy.visit(sandbox_url);
  }
});
```