# Cannot use cypress visit command with create react app

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, cypress

I started to use Cypress a few days ago and i'm already struggling with a simple command such as `visit`.

To figure out what happens, i have created a classic create react app

```
yarn create react-app cypress-test-react
```

then cypress dependencies

```
cd cypress-test-react && yarn add cypress --dev
```

As i'm using Linux, i run this command too:

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb
```

I have implemented something i saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65145948/3852396)

```
describe('Create react app home', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.request('http://localhost:3000').then((response) => {
      if (response.isOkStatusCode) {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000');
      } else {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000');
      }
    });
  });
  it('renders learn react link', () => {
    cy.contains('Learn React');
  });
});
```

with this cypress json:

```
{
  "failOnStatusCode":false,
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "component": {
    "testFiles": "**/*.test.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "componentFolder": "src"
  }
}
```

And finally, i get this issue after running `yarn cypress open-ct --config-file cypress.json`

[image]

I expect some missing packages in my local env but i can't find out what is it.

If some of you already manage this issue, i would really appreciate some help :).
I'm available for more informations

Here is my local config:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86_64
yarn: 1.22.4
node: v15.14.0
```

Comment: can you visit localhost:3000 ? Is something running there ?

Comment: Yes i can visit localhost:3000, i can see the default react page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `yarn cypress open-ct ...` is for component testing.

You can't do `cy.visit()` in a component test, it's used for e2e tests.

Which way do you want to test - the whole page, or a single react component?

If e2e, use `yarn cypress open`.

Comment: Damn dude. Indeed i wanted to test the whole page, not only a single react component. It's a misunderstanding of the command to run ? Can you explain a bit more ?
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: The component testing pattern is [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/introduction). Like a unit test (jest), really.

Comment: Aight, thanks for the link. I really didn't expect such a big difference with two close command line

Comment: Yeah, me too. They shoe-horned the component testing in on top of the e2e base code. Works pretty good though (but I only tested React and Vue).

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing `failOnStatusCode: false` in `cy.request()`. This will not fail your test if it doesn't get 2xx or 3xx response codes.

```js
describe('Create react app home', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.request({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000',
      failOnStatusCode: false,
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.isOkStatusCode) {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
      } else {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
      }
    })
  })
  it('renders learn react link', () => {
    cy.contains('Learn React')
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already tested it this kind of configuration but nothing happened, like it was not there.